# Multiple SPF record for gmail and amazon SES

Tags: email, dns, amazon-ses, spf

Hello I own a website which uses 2 different ways to sent emails to users:

-gmail configured like support@example.com
-amazon SES

The problem is that the emails sent with SES goes allways into spam!
my SPF record looks like: "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all"
my TXT record looks like: "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all"

I have just changed this records as above, should I need to wait 48 hours or something similar?

Are this correct settings? if yes what could be the reason of my problem?

Comment: SPF record mechanisms are denoted with a hyphen character ("-"), not a tilde character ("~"). You should change "~all" to "-all". This may not be the cause of your issue though. Additionally, DNS changes may not take effect until the "TTL" of your DNS record has expired. Take a look in your DNS configuration for this.

Comment: I'm sure you mean Google Apps instead of gmail and in that case, your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941673/what-is-the-correct-spf-record-for-using-both-amazon-ses-and-google-apps

Comment: Nowadays you should not use both SPF and TXT, but only TXT containing the SPF record. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-14.1

Answer (score 0):

The first comment is actually not entirely correct!

Mechanisms can be prefixed with one of four qualifiers:

```
"+"  Pass
"-"  Fail
"~"  SoftFail
"?"  Neutral
```

SoftFail is usually the better choice than Fail because SPF has some flaws and a Fail could prevent some forwarded emails to not arrive at all instead of being flagged as possible spam. (I have experience with those problems since I have worked for several email providers)

Make sure to test your SPF records. You can use this website to test them:
http://spf.myisp.ch

Answer (score 0):

First, as others noted, you are using SoftFail `~all`. From [openspf.org Record Syntax](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax):

> SoftFail: The SPF record has designated the host as NOT being allowed to send but is in transition
>
> Intended action: accept but mark

You should use HardFail `-all` if you want the emails to be rejected when sent from an unauthorized server.

SPF protection is used to prevent [spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing). It's there to define the servers that are authorized to send emails for a certain domain. Generally, if the spf fail, the email will just be rejected and will not get into the spams.

There's a lot of possible reasons an email is getting into the spams, but it's generally because your email has been flagged as spam by a content analysis tool like  [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/). You should contact whoever is managing the email filtering and ask them why exactly your email got in the spams.